# 'Where Not Like' Not excluding ALL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, dbeaver

I am using **Dbeaver & Athena database**. I am trying to exclude based on the condition if name field has 'RG' or 'WS' **anywhere exclude that row**.

```
where NOT Lower(td.territory_name) like '%rg%'  
or NOT lower(td.territory_name)  like  '%ws%'
```

It is not excluding all the rows where the condition applies.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude all the rows having rg or ws in territory_name column. You need to use `and` instead of `or`.

```
where Lower(td.territory_name) not like '%rg%'  
and lower(td.territory_name)  not like  '%ws%'
```

`Lower(td.territory_name) not like '%rg%'` will exclude rows with `rg` but include all the rows with `ws` and `lower(td.territory_name)  not like  '%ws%'` will include all the rows with `rg` if you use `or`.

Comment: I used 'and' but still getting names like 'XX RG', 'RG YYY'. This does not look like working. I am using Athena database & dbeaver.

Comment: Did you also change your code to match @kazi's example? That is using `not like`? Please show your current `WHERE` clause that is still giving the problem.